# Where is candy.war?

Tags: openfire, candy

In the integration of Candy with Openfire it is mentioned to copy `candy.war` into the `<Openfire_root>/plugins` directory. I cannot find where this war is.

Can you please tell me where it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it here http://code.google.com/p/openfire-candy/downloads/list